# Add item to existing menu in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I add an item to an existing menu (in Google Docs) in Google Apps Script?

I can create a *new* menu and add an item to that:

```
DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('MyMenu')
  .addItem('Insert My Thing', 'myFunction')
  .addToUi();
```

But it seems a bit ridiculous to add a whole menu for a single item that should really go under the existing "Insert" menu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently it is **not** possible. Even though the documentation says

> A document, spreadsheet, or form can only contain one menu with a given name. If the same script or another script adds a menu with the same name, the new menu will replace the old.

when I tried the following code

```
DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Tools')
  .addItem('Tool_item', 'toolItem')
  .addToUi();
```

another *Tools* menu was created:

[image]

Comment: Huh...it seems confusing that the user would have a whole different menu for something that he would normally expect to be under "Insert", but I guess that the way it is.

Comment: I agree, I think the integration of custom menus is not the best at the moment. I especially hate the delay between opening the document and the moment a custom menu is added. It's not possible to extend the context menu either which I find very limiting. But I guess that's the way Google tries to separate core functions from extensions.

Comment: The current title of the source of the quote is "Custom Menus in G Suite". It doesn't mention that built-in menus could be customized.

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no.

Yes, you can add your menu ONLY into the existing 'Add-ons'.

No, but nowhere else other than your own customized menu.

The code below may help:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('Sort Current Column with Header until Blank Rows', 'sortCurrentColumn')
    .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e) {
    onOpen(e);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want with custom menus (add, combine...) but **you can't in any way** modify built in menus, they are not accessible from Google-Apps-Script.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, Is this in a spreadsheet?  I added the following code to a spreadsheet - and it correctly replaced the old menu which had one item with a new menu that had the TWO menu items.

```
function someOtherFunction(){
}

function addMenu(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
 name : "Add Menu",
    functionName : "addMenu"
  },{
    name : "Menu 2",
    functionName : "someOtherFunction"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Test Menu", entries);

}

function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Add Menu",
    functionName : "addMenu"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Test Menu", entries);
};
```

Comment: Apologies...I should have specified the is Google Docs.

Comment: I think the question was about adding an item to one of the default menus (e.g. *File*, *Edit*, *View*). In case of custom menus you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a little trick to get a menu and add an item in the same script or another one.

In the same script, you can use the function getMenu() in another function and put .addItem() behind.

**Main menu (menu.gs)**

```
function getMenu() {
  return menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Main menu')
      .addItem('Title', 'function');
}

function onOpen() {
  getMenu().addToUi();
}

function onInstall() {
  getMenu().addToUi();
}
```

Also, with another script, you can import it as a Library and use it like before.

**Another menu (menu2.gs / Where Service is menus.gs imported by Libraries)**

```
function getMenu() {
  return Service.getMenu()
                .addItem('Another Title', 'anotherFunction');
}

function onOpen() {
  getMenu().addToUi();
}

function onInstall() {
  getMenu().addToUi();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Via [Google Developers documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#custom_menus_in_google_docs_sheets_or_forms)

```
// To create an additional Menu-Item to an existing Main-Menu 
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
.addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
.addSeparator()
.addItem('Second item', 'menuItem2')
.addToUi();

// To Create a Menu-Item to a Sub-Menu in an existing Main-Menu
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
.addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
.addSeparator()
.addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Sub-menu')
.addItem('Second item', 'menuItem2'))
.addToUi();
```

Comment: This does answer the question, but merely repeats what the OP has already explained in his question.