# Google Apps Script .add Item recursively?

Tags: javascript, recursion, google-apps-script

So after taking a look at this URL: [Adding Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198863/add-item-to-existing-menu-in-google-apps-script)

The basis is that I can't really add items recursively to a new menu. I seem to have made some progress with the following code:

```
    function onOpen(e) {
             var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu(); 
              var vendorsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Bt4s9aOfjkCyZRvHZMjMdntgID2VYF7Qzmjc7Z7YP1E')

   for(var i = 2; i < 5; i++){
    var j = 4;
   menu.addItem(String(vendorsheet.getRange('A'+ String(i)).getValue()),'Test')

     if(i = j){
      menu.addItem(String(vendorsheet.getRange('A'+ String(i)).getValue()),'Test')
     } else { 
       menu.addItem(String(vendorsheet.getRange('A'+  String(i)).getValue()),'Test')
   }
   }



   menu.addToUi();
 }
```

It only adds two items. It seems as though the menu.addItem function only adds one item per one call of it. You can't use a for loop to call it recursively. If someone could help me add "n" items recursively for any n that would be preferable. Thank you.

Comment: thats not recursively, you mean iteratively ? Are you creating and Add-on or just a menu item in your sheet?

Comment: Year, you're right, it's iterative. Well it doesn't matter right now, I just need to make the menu change dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code is not recursive. As corn3lius rightly says, this code is iterative. I'm pretty sure I know why your code is malfunctioning though.

Your if statement is actually an assignment statement. You want `if (i == j)` not `if (i = j)`

Edit:

To clarify, why you're only getting two entries:

```
1) i = 2        // You assign 2 to i
2) addItem(...) // Entry one
3) if (i = j)   // This is actually considered a trueish statement and gives you your boolean true and sets i = 4
4) addItem(...) // Second entry
5) i++          // i is now equal to 5
6) if (i < 5)   // False, 5 == 5 not 5 < 5, exit the loop.
```

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you for your help! Common beginner mistake.